# Cascade Update one-to-many with NHibernate

Tags: c#, .net, nhibernate, orm, nhibernate-mapping

I'm struggling with a NHibernate mapping problem. I'm using Repository/UnitOfWork pattern, and I'm trying to cascade-persist my objects through update method. For an example: I can alter Foo, adding/updating/deleting Bar objects and it's all ok. But when I try to add Son and Daughter objects to "Bar", and update Foo (to persist Bar and its child objects), Son and Daughter objects are not persisted to DB, only Foo with all Bars (without Son/Daughter objects).

```
public class Foo
{
    public int FooID {get; set;}
    public string Name {get; set;}
    public virtual IList<Bar> Bars {get; set;}    
    public Foo(){}
}    
public class Bar
{
    public int BarID {get; set;}
    public string Name {get; set;}
    public Foo Foo {get; set;}
    public virtual IList<Son> Sons {get; set;}
    public virtual IList<Daughter> Daughters {get; set;}
    public Bar(){}
}    
public class Son
{
    public int SonID {get; set;}
    public string Name {get; set;}
    public virtual Bar Bar {get; set;}
    public Son(){}
}    
public class Daughter
{
    public int DaughterID {get; set;}
    public string Name {get; set;}
    public virtual Bar Bar {get; set;}
    public Daughter(){}
}    

//on Foo.hbm.xml I have:
...
<bag name="Bar" table="Bar" inverse="true" cascade="all-delete-orphan" lazy="false">
  <key column="FooID" />
  <one-to-many class="Bar" />
</bag>

//on Bar.hbm.xml I have
...
<many-to-one name="Foo" column="FooID" class="Foo" lazy="false" />
<bag name="Son" table="Son" inverse="true" cascade="all-delete-orphan" lazy="false">
  <key column="SonID" />
  <one-to-many class="Son" />
</bag>

<bag name="Daughter" table="Daughter" inverse="true" cascade="all-delete-orphan" lazy="false">
  <key column="DaughterID" />
  <one-to-many class="Daughter" />
</bag>

//on Son/Daughter.hbm.xmlI have
...
<many-to-one name="Bar" column="BarID" class="Bar" lazy="false" />
```

Where I'm doing it wrong? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Try persisting Test1 and Test2 before adding it to your collection just as a test.

Comment: Hi @DavidC thank you for answering. but If I create Bar at runtime, I don't have BarID to map my Son/Daughter objects. The only pre-existant object I have is Foo. This way, those "Bar" objects can be persisted, because I've already have FooID. So, NHibernate have to find a way to persist my "Bar" object first (putting an ID on them), and then store corresponding son/daughter objects (mapping with BarID).

Comment: If you are letting NHibernate generate your ID's, as soon as you "attach" a new object to the current session, it gets an identity.  Then you just add them to a persisted collection.  I have seen this work when just adding them to the persisted collection doesn't flush to the database.

Comment: E.g. Call session.Save(newObject), and after that, newObject.Id will be populated.  Assuming you are using nhibernate to generate your identities.

Comment: Yeah @DavidC , I saw that nHibernate populates the ID property of Bar, but how should I have to do, to populate Son/Daughter "Bar" property, with recently persisted one?
For an example: First, persist Foo and Bar (now we have Foo.Bar and Bar.ID), then persist Bar.Son (Son.Bar = Bar, so at Son Table we have refs to Bar (Son.BarID = BarID)) ?

Comment: OK, I see, you are creating a recursive relationship.  I thought the Bar in the Children were new Bar objects.  I'll paste this under answer so it shows up as code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following test :

```
    var newFoo = new Foo();
    var newBar = new Bar();
    var newSon = new Son();

    _session.Save(newBar);

    newSon.Bar = newBar;
    newBar.Sons.Add(newSon);
    Foo.Bar = newBar;
```

Comment: Please try and provide commented code if you're not adding a description as a part of your answer.

Comment: Sorry, I thought the comment chain on the OP was enough.

Comment: It's always nice to roll-up everything into the answer whenever possible. (It won't get flagged in the review queue then.) :-)

Comment: Thank you for clarification @DavidC . I did something like you said and a plus: I've changed my hbm.xml cascade="all-delete-orphan" mapping tag just to cascade="all". I did this because I was getting transient object exception. Now all things work. Thank you.

Comment: You are very welcome, good luck with nHibernate.  It has a steep learning curve, but is awesome once you get used to it.